# On update trigger not working with json data type

Tags: mysql, json, triggers, database-trigger

I have created a trigger as follows:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER facility_availabilities_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON facility_availabilities FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO facility_availabilities_clone
  (id,facility_id,availability,`date`,created_at,updated_at)
  VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.facility_id, NEW.`date`, NEW.availability, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at);
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

one of my field i.e **availability** is json data type and stores the data as shown in the image:

[image]

when I try to update the master table i.e **facility_availabilities** I get the following error:

#3140 - Invalid JSON text: "The document root must not follow by other values." at position 4 in value for column 'facility_availabilities_clone.availability'.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error for json data, try using JSON_ARRAY function in this case

VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.facility_id, NEW.`date`, JSON_ARRAY(NEW.availability), NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at);